# how to divide single row into multiple coumns in excel(i have thousand records)

Tags: excel

how to split if the rows with ID

**Ex:**
Consider two columns A & B

```
A   B
1  apple,orange
2  orange,banana
```

Then how to split the data based on ID. Expected output like below:

```
A  B
1 apple
1 orange
2 orange
2 banana
```

Comment: consider two columns A & B
A   B
1   apple,banana
1   orange,fruit

It answer should be
A   B
1  apple
1 orange

Comment: This would need vba. Just with excel its not possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand Table with Delimited Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48405462/expand-table-with-delimited-column)